# Compare two files and add new column to file one, if true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm very new to python, so please be kind :P

I try to find values, which are the same in two files. In File 1, I have more columns than in file 2.

So I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv('File2.csv', delimiter=';',encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx')

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

for index_xls, row_xls in df_2.iterrows():
        excel = row_xls['Source-a'],row_xls['Source-b'],row_xls['Target-1'],row_xls['Target-2']

        for index_csv, row_csv in df_1.iterrows():
            csv = row_csv['Source-a'],row_csv['Source-b'],row_csv['Target-1'],row_csv['Target-2']
         
            pgv = excel == csv

            if pgv == True:
                print(excel)
```

Now I want to add a new column to file1.xlsx for every "true" value from the for loop.

In File1.xlsx are more columns as in file2.csv.

I get the right results in the variable "excel" but I don't know how to go on from this.

Short: I want the values from the variable "excel" and compare these with 4 columns of file1.xls and if they match, I want to add an "true" to the matched row.

I hope that I described it so somebody can understand my problem here :D

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are redundant; `pd.read_csv` and `pd.read_excel` already return DataFrames:

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

On to your main problem:

```py
cols = ['Source-a','Source-b','Target-1','Target-2']
present_in_both = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=cols,how='inner')
```

Comment: thanky for your help. this seems to work fine. but one question: If i write it in an xlsx file, it works great, but why do i have an new dataframe for each match, if i print(preset in both)?